# How to query markdown files of a specific language in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, gatsby

I've a folder `content/projects` with files in the following manner:

- `project-a.de.md`
- `project-a.en.md`
- `project-b.de.md`
- `project-b.en.md`

Now how could I build a component which display some of this projects, who have the `featured` flag in their frontmatter and are of a specific language?

I've created the following component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Content from '../Content'
import { FeaturedProjectsQuery } from '../../../graphql-types'

const FeaturedProjects: React.FC = () => {
  const projects = useStaticQuery<FeaturedProjectsQuery>(graphql`
    query FeaturedProjects {
      allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: { regex: "/(content/projects)/" }, frontmatter: { featured: { eq: true } } }) {
        nodes {
          frontmatter {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  return (
    <Content>
      <h2>
        <FormattedMessage id="navigation.projects" />
      </h2>
      {projects.allMarkdownRemark.nodes.map(p => {
        return <div>{p.frontmatter?.title}</div>
      })}
    </Content>
  )
}

export default FeaturedProjects
```

This works, but I would have to filter for the current language (which I get over a React context) within TypeScript, even though I think it's the perfect task for the GraphQL query, because it's made for selecting things.

Unfortunately I cannot use variables in the static query. How would you achieve that?

### Tl;dr

I've tried to create the query with a variable, but string interpolation is not allowed in graphql tag.

```
... 
allMarkdownRemark(filter: { fileAbsolutePath: {
 regex: `/(content/projects).*\\.${lang}\\.md$/` ...
}
...
```

[image: String interpolation is forbidden]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems [string interpolation isn't supported](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5090#issuecomment-383982107) - too bad!

You could use [gatsby-plugin-pathdata](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-pathdata/) to add a `lang` field to your nodes.

In `gatsby-config`, in the plugins section add

```
{
  resolve: "gatsby-plugin-pathdata",
  options: {
    matchNodeType: "MarkdownRemark",
    extract: [
      {
        name: "lang",
         // Regex isn't my strong suit so the `selector` might need some work
         // This matches any 2 lower case letter, between 2 dots, followed by 
         // the `md` extension 
         // ====================
         // ex:  for `/path/to/the/file/project-b.de.md`, the `lang` field
         // will be `de`
        selector: /.+\/.*([a-z][a-z])+\.md$/, 
        replacer: "$1"
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

This adds a `field.lang` to all your markdown files - and the fields can also be used for filtering.

With that in place you can use a query with a variable to select the files

```
query MyQuery($lang: String) {
  allMarkdownRemark(filter: {fields: {lang: {eq: $lang}}}) {
    nodes {
      frontmatter {
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are probably other ways to get this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering my question. It's an interesting plugin you suggest, but I don't understand why I need it. I can achieve the same with a RegEx as described above. You suggesting to move away from a static query. I don't know how I can gather all featured projects within a page with a normal query? Maybe you can point me to the documentation. I'm really stuck here.

Comment: I think you would have to use a query with parameters to get only the files with the desired language - I don't know of any way to pass parameters to a static query. I missed the requirement that this should be a static query. 

Why the plugin? I couldn't use a query param in a regex. It might be a bit of over engineering :)

Comment: You don't need an extra plugin to do this, but bamse is correct that you can't currently pass parameters to a static query. Gatsby can't run query on client side anyway, so it can't possibly know in advance which data your component needs. @coreyward has already share the possible solution in his comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59486966/how-to-query-markdown-files-of-a-specific-language-in-gatsby#comment106474988_60191174

Answer (score 2):

The way I've tackled this in the past is to query for all of the data that I might need (in this case, all featured projects of any language), and then use JS to filter based on the current locale. This has the downside of loading a bit more data client-side, but it won't impact the statically rendered HTML page size.

Another approach I've used is to use the `createPage` API to pass in each language as context, which is then available to your query as a variable, then to simply render each page in each language and to change the URL to switch between them (i.e. using Gatsby's `navigate`). This works well, but you do need to devise a way to determine the URL for each language, but you probably will use that for your `rel="alternate"` links as well anyways.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. I understand the approach you describe, but I think it doesn't fit my problem that well. I'm trying to display a selected list of projects within a page. Let's say the page should list the last 5 projects, which are available in English. I'm not sure if it works with the approach you describe or I don't know how.

Comment: @Robin For that I would really just use client-side filtering. The only other strategy would be to utilize a suite of static queries and then either conditionally render language-specific components or to extract the raw query result data from the build and reinject it dynamically when a language is selected (which is way overkill for the scenario you're in).

Comment: That's a pity, that something this simple seems to be that hard. Users don't change the language that often, so most of them get too much data, like the featured projects in all available languages and all other elements like this. I understand Gatsby as a static page generator and with "client-side filtering" we move away from this principle.

Comment: @Robin What is the alternative? You're building a collection of static HTML files that are served up by a typical web server like nginx. There is no server-side runtime, and thus there is no way to dynamically execute GraphQL queries based on changing inputs from your front-end.

Comment: I understand that and that's what I want. A static file with only the content of one language. Gatsby should generate a page for a specific language with some language specific markdown files, which contain the projects. I don't understand why I would need client side filtering for that.

Comment: @Robin Ah, then all you need to do is generate a page for each language in `gatsby-node.js` (just call `createPage` for each one). There are lots of tutorials and examples on this. This is what I outlined in my second example/approach.